# Are functions with MonadIO constraint less powerful than ones with IO?

Tags: haskell

[There is an interesting claim](https://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2016/03/why-i-prefer-typeclass-based-libraries) that `MonadIO` constraint tells more about the function using it than if it were using `IO` directly:

```
foo :: MonadIO m => m a -> m a
```

> Reason: MonadIO requires that the IO be in positive, not negative,
>   position.
>
> This lets us know, for example, that foo is safe to use in a
>   continuation-based monad like ContT or Conduit.

How does `MonadIO` enforce this? Is it always the case or is it related to the example?